# Unity - Firebase App Initialization Exception

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement Firebase Firestore in my hobby Unity project to create a leaderboard like feature. In order to that, I've implemented all libraries in my project then wrote the function to do so.

Here is my initialization function that I call in awake function in my script file.

```
 Firebase.AppOptions options = new Firebase.AppOptions();
        options.ApiKey = "AIza***********************************"; // SameApiKeyInGoogleServicesJson
        options.AppId = "1:406955949074:android:************"; // SameAppIdInGoogleServicesJson
        options.ProjectId = "fishing-***********"; // SameProjectIdInGoogleServicesJson
        options.StorageBucket = "fishing-*************.com"; // SameStorageBucketInGoogleServicesJson
        options.DatabaseUrl = new System.Uri("https://fishing-*************.firebaseio.com"); // SameDatabaseUrlInGoogleServicesJson
        
        var app = FirebaseApp.Create(options);
        var task = FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
            if(task.Result == DependencyStatus.Available){
                Debug.Log("Firebase correctly Initialized");
            }
            else{
                Debug.Log("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + task.Result);
            }
        });
```

That code works in Emulator but it does not work in a real Android device (with debug apk).

Can anyone explain me where did I do wrong? Are there any missing steps?

I have tried to implement Firebase in my Unity project but I failed to do.

Comment: Hello,

To clarify, is there a particular reason you are configuring the app options manually instead of using configuration files as described in [Add Firebase to your Unity project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#config-files-objects)? The  correspondence between the config files and AppOptions are discussed in [Understand Firebase Projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#config-files-objects)